# google local search results in XML/JSON format

Tags: google-maps, google-local-search

I would like to issue a local search on Google maps (e.g. list of restaurants for a given location), and I would like to get the (Restaurants data) data back in JSON/XML or other similar format. What's the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

I found this http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#center_localsearch if it helps